# How to give the data to serializer with JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model and serializer with JSONField

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = m.Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then,I want to set the data to serializer class,

However some how `serializer.is_valid()` faild.

I have tested two pettern `data1` `data2`

```
    temp_data = {"data":"test"}

    data1 = {"detail":temp_data}   # test_data1
    data2 = {"detail":json.dumps(temp_data)} # test_data2 

    print(data1)  # {'detail': {'data': 'test'}}
    print(data2)  # {'detail': '{"data": "test"}'}

    instance = self.get_object()
    
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance,data = data1) # or data2

    if serializer.is_valid(): 
       # serializer
    else:
        print("is_valid failed")
```

What data should I give to this serializer?

And is there any method to debug is_valid()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the data in right way, but as you are updating partially, you need to pass one more parameter:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=data1, partial=True)
```

To debug the `is_valid` method, you can either throw exceptions from it like `.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`; **or** in your code, print `serializer.errors` in else block to print the exact errors. More information on validation can be found in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation).